# Making Easy Pie Charts. Anyone?

Tags: html, css

I found these pie charts titled `Easy Charts` in a theme I was playing around on. I want to make them for my own project. Anyone have any ideas or know somewhere they already exist that I could get them at? I'm not even sure what they are called.

[image]

Comment: Which theme? Can we have a look?

Comment: http://themeforest.net/item/cascade-flat-responsive-bootstrap-admin-template/full_screen_preview/6238081

Comment: Had you shown us your code and asked "how can I create pie-charts" (using either CSS or JavaScript) the question might have still been closed, as a duplicate, but it would, at least, have been on-topic. As it is, as the explanation below summarises, we don't recommend tools or libraries, since opinions are, almost exclusively and by definition, a subjective matter of opinion and preference. Further, the blog entry "[Q&A is hard, let's go shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)" further explains the problems inherent in 'shopping questions.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Google Charts Library](https://developers.google.com/chart/?csw=1)**

**[JS Charts](http://www.jscharts.com/)**

**[HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)**

**[Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/)**

**[13 Useful JavaScript Solutions for Charts and Graphs](http://webdesignledger.com/resources/13-useful-javascript-solutions-for-charts-and-graphs)**

Answer (score 0):

There's a lovely library called Highcharts that I can heartedly recommend for creating numerous types of charts
http://www.highcharts.com/

It allows for manipulation of datasets into pie-charts, line and spline etc.

Great documentation, customization options and works terrific even in legacy browsers.